# Search by date MODX REVO

Tags: sql, modx, modx-revolution

How do I filter records by date?

I have the value `1639082700` which is equal to `2021-12-09 23:45:00`. I need to find all data for `2021-12-09` which is equal to `1638997200`.

Comment: What snippet are you going to use for filter needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert integers to actual dates.
For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM modx_table 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(column_name,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2021-12-09'
```

Comment: Thanks, I already found the solution for this myself